# Android SharedPreferences saving top scores for a game

Tags: android

i am new to android. I want to save 5 highscores for my game. I am using SharedPreferences
for that. How can I save more than one score in SharedPreferences? I can assume that there must be a checking each time completing a level. But how can i populate 5 highscores?

Comment: Different keys. eg highscore1, highscore2, etc.

Comment: i have already tried that. but suppose you have a score 2600 and there are already scores 3200, 2400, 2300 exist. then 3200 will remain in 1st position, 2600 will be put on 2nd pos, 2400 in third and 2300 in 4th. so 2400 and 2300 indexes are decremented. my question is how can i maintain this flow ???

Comment: Implement a sorting algorithm, then rewrite the whole sharedpreferences. Since you only have 5 scores, this wouldn't slow your app down.

Comment: will try this...thnks @A--C

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Say that you want to only store the scores (no names). Put all your scores in an array. Then use

```
Arrays.sort (myIntArray);
```

This sorts it into ascending order, so you need to reverse it.

This means in your SharedPreferences writing operation, start with 4 then work backwards..

```
sharedPreferences.putInt( "HighScore1", myIntArray [4] );
sharedPreferences.putInt( "HighScore2", myIntArray [3] );
```

etc.

For best results, you would have a "default" value of sort, such as `-1` for scores that don't exist. That way when you display to the screen, you can check for `-1` then output "None" or not output anything at all.

Answer (score 0):

Simply give each one a unique key:

```
SharedPreferences.Editor spEdit = getDefaultSharedPreferences().edit();
spEdit.putInt( "FirstHighScore", firstHighScore );
spEdit.putInt( "SecondHighScore", secondHighScore );
// Etc.
spEdit.commit();
```

Comment: "i have already tried that. but suppose you have a score 2600 and there are already scores 3200, 2400, 2300 exist. then 3200 will remain in 1st position, 2600 will be put on 2nd pos, 2400 in third and 2300 in 4th. so 2400 and 2300 indexes are decremented. my question is how can i maintain this flow ???" --- @Ralgha... any idea bro ???

Comment: @tcse9 : simply and easy way is first add all prefrences in ArrayList from SharedPreferences and then add new score also in arraylist . second after adding all elements in ArrayList sort in acoding to your need ASC or DESC order and third after shorting store it in SharedPreferences

Comment: right you are, i will go for this methodology, thanks man --@ ρяσѕρєя K